# Why が instead of は here for reasoning clauses?

Tags: grammar

Why is it が and not は for the bolded particle?:

> お寺を見に行くつもりでしたが、天気**が**よくなかったから、行きませんでした。
>   We were planning to go to see a temple, but we didn't because the weather was not good.

Is it also OK to replace that section 天気がよくなかったから with よくなかった天気でしたから?

Comment: は vs が: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/22/whats-the-difference-between-wa-%E3%81%AF-and-ga-%E3%81%8C

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 1):

In Japanese grammar, が is usually used with subjects in subordinate clauses and は is often used with subjects in main clauses.

よくなかった天気でしたから is correct in grammar, I think, but it sounds weird. よくなかった and でした are both expressions of past tense, so it should become duplicate when appearing in one sentence.

Comment: Thanks, when you say "usually" -- does that mean I'm grammatically allowed to use は instead of が?

Comment: No. Although it makes no difference in conveying your idea if you use は instead of が here, it is a kind of misuse in grammar. I suggest you stick to using が in subordinate clauses ALWAYS.

Comment: Thanks -- never seen that advice before and it makes me think that が is more commonly seen in sentences then.

Comment: In fact, there are rare cases that は is used in subordinate clauses, but to avoid mistakes, が is always correct, I think. Especially as a non-native Japanese speaker, it is a prudent usage. By the way, it is just a personal suggestion from my practical experience.

Comment: Helpful, thank you!

Comment: Personally, I think it's a mistake to consider は and が as alternatives to one another. は is more like "something that can replace a が to mark the topic or contrastive, for which purpose it could also be replacing an を, or be following after a に, で, と, or other particle."

Comment: I've been thinking about why「よくなかった天気でしたから」sounds so unnatural, but I can't quite put my finger on it. I wonder if there's an explanation for it.